# JasperReports: getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate excel reports from *Java*. I am using *Spring* on *Java* side and *iReport* to develop the jasper files. I am getting `ClassCast` exception although the report runs fine on *iReport*. The language I am using at *iReport* side for report is *Java*.

The whole error Console is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.getNumberCellValue(JRAbstractExporter.java:1198)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.getTextValue(JRAbstractExporter.java:1139)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.createTextCell(JRXlsExporter.java:737)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.exportText(JRXlsExporter.java:684)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportPage(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:1195)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:940)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:629)
    at com.ultimatix.dao.SubmissionReportJasperDaoImpl.mainReportXLS(SubmissionReportJasperDaoImpl.java:590)
    at com.ultimatix.service.SubmissionReportJasperServiceImpl.excelDownload(SubmissionReportJasperServiceImpl.java:159)
```

Is there some mismatch of data types within the report or some other issue. Since *iReport* generates the o/p, I have no clue what is wrong at *Java* end.

My Implementation:

```
    String mainDir="D:/Reports _ B_Type/";

        String[] sheetNames={"Contract Details","Quick Selection","Basic Details","Billing Related Parameter","Discounts Applicable","Charges Applicable","Other Parameter","Slab-Wise Rates"};

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        contractId = (String) contractData.get(DBConstants.PROC_PI_CONTRACT_ID);
        versionNo = (String) contractData.get(DBConstants.VERSION_NO);
        String sql=SQLQuery.getCommonHeaderDetailForFCmVersion();
        ByteArrayOutputStream os1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            contractDataList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,new Object[] {contractId,versionNo});
            for (Map<String,Object> row : contractDataList) {
                contractingCompany=(String) row.get(DBConstants.FCM_CONTRACT_INFO_CONTRACTING_COMPANY);
                customerName=(String) row.get(DBConstants.FCM_CONTRACT_INFO_MV_CUSTOMER_NAME);
                startDate=(String) row.get(DBConstants.FCM_CONTRACT_INFO_MV_CONTRACT_START_DATE);
                endDate=(String) row.get(DBConstants.FCM_CONTRACT_INFO_MV_CONTRACT_END_DATE);
                if(null != row.get(DBConstants.FCM_CONTRACT_INFO_MV_TOTAL_CONTRACT_VALUE))
                {   
                    tcsContractValue= row.get(DBConstants.FCM_CONTRACT_INFO_MV_TOTAL_CONTRACT_VALUE).toString();
                }
                contractStatus="E";
            }

            /*parameters to be passed in report */

            parameters.put("ContractId", contractId); 
            parameters.put("VersionNo", versionNo);
            parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",mainDir);
            parameters.put("ContractingCompany",contractingCompany);
            parameters.put("CustomerName",customerName);
            parameters.put("StartDate",startDate);
            parameters.put("EndDate",endDate);
            parameters.put("TcsContractValue",tcsContractValue);
            parameters.put("ContractStatus",contractStatus);

            connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);

            String reportTemplatePath = null;//path to find the template report


            String fileSep = File.pathSeparator;

            if(fileSep.equals(":") ){

            }else{
                reportTemplatePath =mainDir + "Main Report.jasper";
            }
            JasperPrint jasperPrint;

                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                        reportTemplatePath,parameters,connection);

            JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();

            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);

            exporterXLS.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,Boolean.FALSE);

            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,
                    Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES,sheetNames);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.CREATE_CUSTOM_PALETTE,Boolean.TRUE);//to generate closest matching color when report generated from java end.

try{
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, os1);
            **exporterXLS.exportReport();**
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
}`enter code here`
```

This is where i get the exception.

Comment: What version of *JR* library are you using? What version of *iReport* did you use?

Comment: I am using jasperreport5.0.1 and the very same version of iReport

Comment: I would also like to add it was running successfully and I have downloaded few reports before today.

Comment: I have 8 sub reports embedded in it each with few tables and crstabs of their own.So ,very difficult to pin point anything whatsoever and also not made easy by the fact that it is executing perfectly with iReport.

Comment: I just now checked all the sub reports.They are all working fine with the same java code,only facing issues with this main report which includes the sub reports.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug that's been fixed at JasperReports trunk revision 6340.

Build a JasperReports jar from the SVN trunk (or patch the 5.0.1 sources) to check if it's the same problem.